# What exactly does TO_DATE return

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, to-date

I'm coming from SQL Server world, and I'm struggling a little with dates conversion in Oracle. I have a table with a `DATE` column. I'm trying to return rows from a contracts table filtered by date.

I can select the following from the contracts table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TradeDate,
    TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
FROM Contracts
ORDER BY TradeDate DESC;
```

which happily returns all rows from the `Contracts` table, although strangely the result-set is shown with the two dates formatted differently:

| TradeDate | TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD') |
| --- | --- |
| 2024/01/23 | 24-JUL-23 |
| 2023/12/21 | 24-JUL-23 |
| 2023/12/20 | 24-JUL-23 |
| 2023/12/19 | 24-JUL-23 |
| 2023/12/18 | 24-JUL-23 |
| 2023/12/15 | 24-JUL-23 |

but if I try to add a where clause comparing `TradeDate` to the date I've created from `TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TradeDate,
    TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
FROM Contracts
WHERE TradeDate = TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
ORDER BY TradeDate DESC;
```

I get the error:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
> ORA-02063: preceding line from 
> 01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
> *Cause: Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace). If the "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly, with no extra whitespace.
> *Action: Correct the format string to match the literal.

There's clearly nothing wrong with the usage of the `TO_DATE` function in the first `SELECT` statement and it's the same expression I use in the `WHERE` clause. However the error appears to be related to how `TO_DATE` is called. What is going on and why can't I compare the two dates together? Also, why does the result-set show the two dates in different formats?

**Update**: turns out that `TradeDate` is, in fact, a string. Joy.

Comment: is "TradeDate" column is in "DATE" datatype ? if not u need to use "TO_DATE" function for the column which u are trying to compare

Comment: I'm (annoyingly) unable to see the table definition due to security reasons; it's an assumption I've made. I'm starting to come to the conclusion that it is a string, as I can add the calculated column ```CASE WHEN TradeDate = 'bob' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END``` without error.

Comment: can u try this : SELECT  DISTINCT TradeDate,
        TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
FROM    Contracts
WHERE   to_date(TradeDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') = TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
ORDER BY TradeDate DESC;

Comment: I get a row with: | 2023/07/24 | 24-JUL-23 |. I'm pretty sure it must be a string, as your test indicates.

Comment: The [`dump`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/DUMP.html) function will tell you everything about a column's actual contents.

Comment: In answer to the question in the title, [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html) accepts a string and returns a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_DATE` transforms a sting into a `DATE` value. Are you really sure column `TradeDate` is a `DATE` value? I would assume, it is rather a `VARCHAR2` data type (which would be a poor design)

Your query

```
SELECT 
   TradeDate,
   TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
...
```

would return two `DATE` values, and it is not possible to display the same data type in different formats - unless you do any explicit formatting.

Check the data type of the column, you can use

```
SELECT DUMP(TradeDate, 1016) 
FROM ...
```

It should return something like

```
Typ=12 Len=...
```

For a list of data types see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6

Perhaps the data type is `TIMESTAMP` rather than `DATE` and your user session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting is different to `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` setting. This also could explain the different outputs.

**Update**

As you found out, `TradeDate` is a string. Usually you should compare `DATE` values with `DATE` values, not strings. You can do

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TO_DATE(TradeDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') as TradeDate,
    TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
FROM Contracts
WHERE TO_DATE(TradeDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') = TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
ORDER BY TradeDate DESC;
```

or with `DATE` literals:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TO_DATE(TradeDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') as TradeDate,
    DATE '2023-07-24'
FROM Contracts
WHERE TO_DATE(TradeDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD') = DATE '2023-07-24'
ORDER BY TradeDate DESC;
```

However, the best solution would be to change the data type of column `TradeDate` to proper `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

TO_DATE function in oracle will take three arguments like this

> TO_DATE (string, format, nls_language)

Second and third argument is optional

First argument is a string value which we need to converted to a DATE value. It can be a value of any data type CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2.

Second argument is format argument is optional. If you omit the format, the string must be in the standard oracle date format which is DD-MON-YY e.g., 27-DEC-23.

Third argument is an expression that specifies the language for day and month names in the string. This nls_language argument has the form "NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = language" and this ls_language argument is optional. If you omit it, the TO_DATE() function will use the default language for your session.

In most cases, only first 2 arguments will use for to_date .The TO_DATE() function returns a DATE value which is corresponding to the input string.

so in your case

```
WHERE   TradeDate = TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

i am assuming "TradeDate" column is having "VARCHAR" or any other datatype other than date so u cant compare a string to date format. so u need to convert the TradeDate column into DATE format for comparing.

if TradeDate having values like this "2024/01/23" then u need to use TO_DATE(TradeDate,'YYYY/MM/DD'). [ i.e. Use the format which is there in the column of TradeDate ]

so try like this

> ```
> SELECT  DISTINCT TradeDate,
>         TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
> FROM    Contracts
> WHERE   TO_DATE(TradeDate,'YYYY/MM/DD') = TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
> ORDER BY TO_DATE(TradeDate,'YYYY/MM/DD') DESC;
> ```

if u want to use order by DATE then u also need to convert that to date format otherwise it will order by string desc

Comment: This statement is wrong: "*If you omit the format, the string must be in the standard oracle date format which is DD-MON-YY e.g., 27-DEC-2023*" First of all, `DD-MON-YY` obviously does not match format `27-DEC-2023` (2 digit year vs. 4 digits). If you omit the format, the Oracle takes the current user session `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` value - which you should not rely on, because it may change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

To just answer the question from title "What exactly does TO_DATE return" (now when it is clear that datatype of TradeDate is VarChar)
TO_DATE() function converts a string into Oracle DATE datatype meaning that...
TO_DATE() function returns 7 bytes representing Century, Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes and Seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output of the **first query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TradeDate,
    TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
FROM Contracts
ORDER BY TradeDate DESC;
```

It seems like

- Your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `DD-MON-YY` (See TradeDate in the result --> `24-JUL-23`)
- Column `TradeDate` is `VARCHAR` column with dates as a string in the `YYYY/MM/DD` format.

Now, let's look into your **second query** where you are trying to compare the `TradeDate` column data with some date which is `TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')`

```
WHERE TradeDate = TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Oracle will try to compare this `VARCHAR` column to `DATE` literal after converting the `VARCHAR` column to `DATE` data type.

For converting the string to date, oracle will use the format specified in the **NLS** parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which is `DD-MON-YY` for your session.

Means Oracle will try to do this conversion as follows:

```
TO_DATE(TradeDate,'DD-MON-YY')
--Taking one of the examples from data of TradeDate column
TO_DATE('2024/01/23','DD-MON-YY')
```

Which is obviously not convertible so Oracle is throwing an error.

You need to convert your `TradeDate` to date before comparing it with date as follows:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(TradeDate,'YYYY/MM/DD') = TO_DATE('2023/07/24', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

OR you can simply do string comparison as follows:

```
WHERE TradeDate = '2023/07/24'
```